# Not symlinking one or two files inside symlinked directory

Tags: linux, centos

Is there a way not to symlink one or two files within a symlinked directory in CentOS?

I've got the entire directory symlinked but there are two css files that I would like to use the current copy for the website

Comment: Do you use some version control system, e.g. `git` ? It sounds like you want branching in it...

Comment: I use git but this is to support multiple functions from one core for multiple websites with different settings

Answer (score 1):

In short: no.

Another way to do this would be to symlink all the files in that directory, except those you want local copy of.

Still another way to go might be using unionfs or aufs to union-mount the original directory and a directory containing the files you need local, with the directory containing local files being "on top".

Say, your original directory is `orig`, the directory with files that should be local is `local`, the union directory is `union`, and you want files from both directories to be writable. Then you can union-mount them like this:

```
unionfs-fuse local=RW:orig=RW union
```

And unmount like this:

```
fusermount -u union
```

See unionfs manpage (unionfs-fuse(8) at least on Debian) for details.